# Limitations of Quantum Chemistry

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I have a physics background and I am interested in the applications of quantum mechanics in predicting chemical reactions, and I’m wondering where should I start?

I am particularly interested in the Quantum chemistry of species dissolved in water. How could one compute the time evolution of a chemical system taking into account a carrier medium such as water?

Could one use quantum chemistry to predict the affinity of a certain compound of a particular chemical?

How could the existence of catalysts, temperature and pressure be taken into account when predicting reactions?

Or are these well beyond the scope of current quantum chemistry?

Comment: So... you're asking how big and complex system can be practically modelled with taking account of QM? Well, that quite *depends*.  Even that would be probably too broad, and you're asking more then that.

Comment: Since you are considering *modeling* the system you might want to post your question at Matter Modeling SE. It's all within the scope of quantum chemistry, though. However simulation of quantum systems is **very** computationally costly. This is the main limitation.